# Three.js JavaScript 3D library on a WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, 3d, three.js, javascript

I wanted to use Three.js JavaScript 3D library on my WordPress site, so I tried the three.min.js in the:

1. body of a post

   `<script src="/three.min.js"></script>`
2. then the footer

   `<script type='text/javascript' src='/three.min.js'></script>`
3. and now the Pinboard: Theme Functions (functions.php) file

   `function pinboard_enqueue_scripts() {
   wp_register_script('three.min', '/three.min.js', true);
   wp_enqueue_script( 'three.min' );
   }
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pinboard_enqueue_scripts' );`

Unfortunately the cube from [Mr.doob’s page](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js) is not showing up on my [Cube page](http://icolora.com/cube/).

Your help in running the Three.js on my WordPress site would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well that has also a lot to do with CSS ^^ I do the same at http://lizkats.com, maybe get some inspiration there.
In the wordpress theme editor I edited the header file (header.php) to include both the library and the script there. I used an absolute URL (i.e. I cheated, maybe you have more patience and find a better way) and inserted libraries and script like following:

```
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
    <!-- Here (after head & body in Heaper.php) starts the stuff I added myself -->
    <div id="3dcontainer" style="position: fixed; z-index: -1;"></div>
    <div id="page" class="hfeed site">
    <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner" style="overflow: visible;">


    <script src="http://lizkats.com/wp-content/fromGame/three.js"></script>
    <script src="http://lizkats.com/wp-content/fromGame/models/modelMeerkatPoseWeb.js"></script>
<script>

        var container, stats;

        var camera, scene, renderer, objects;

        var clock = new THREE.Clock();


        function init() {

            container = document.getElementById('3dcontainer');

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.5, 200 );
            camera.position.set( 0.4, 0.42, 0.9 );

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            // ...

            // Renderer

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: true } );
            renderer.setClearColor( 0x453326, 1);
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            animate();
        }

        init();

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );


            render();
        }

        function render() {

            var delta = clock.getDelta();

            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }
</script>
```

The *3dcontainer* is where I insert the canvas object.

Further you'll also have to update your style.css in order to make it look the way you want. Here's a paste of my current (entire) stylesheet: http://pastebin.com/9uUiAZhY

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for your response @Doidel. The [Lizards and Meerkats][1] project looks good!

Could you please provide more details regarding the following:
1. What is the location of the 3dcontainer?
2. What do you include in the 3dcontainer?
3. What to update in the style.css?

Your help is much appreciated.

Thank you.

  [1]: http://lizkats.com/play/

Comment: Well that's a lot you ask for there :) I added some more to give you a better idea of what I'm doing. But I can't tell you what to do exactly 'cause a) my stylesheet is based on a specific version of the wordpress theme "twentythirteen". If you just copy paste it it won't work unless you have the exact same version as base. b) you might want it to look different c) I have styles in there I changed in order to apply my own color theme. And you probably want a different one :) I fear I can't do more than that for you. You really have to figure out the rest for yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much for your responses @Doidel! I just left a comment on your “About the author” page. Your help is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Stackoverflow is a place to ask for guidance and (limited) help. If you want someone to *work for you* then you could e.g. hire a freelancer or a local web development company. I myself am not up for freelancing. Glad to help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @Doidel! As per your recommendations, the style.css and header.php have been updated, but unfortunately the cube is still not showing up on the Cube page: http://icolora.com/cube/. Your help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is popular search, so I decided to write little help for feature readers.

I'm assuming that you have properly installed and working Wordpress.

**Installation without bundlers**

The simplest way to make example three.js cube working on your Wordpress home page, following [three.js docs](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Installation):

**1.** Depending on your Wordpress configuration open index.php / page.php

**2.** First we need to import library, there are two common ways to do that via : npm or cdn.

CDN:

```
<script type="module">
// Find the latest version by visiting https://cdn.skypack.dev/three.
import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.137.5';

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
</script>
```

NPM ([check Downloading and installing Node.js and npm if needed](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm)):

Open your terminal and run `npm install three`. This will create `node_modules` folder in your directory, which contains library. Example provided in three.js docs, assumes that you will bundle html. Although we will import our library without bundling for the needs of this question.

Open functions.php and enqueue library:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'three-min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/node_modules/three/build/three.min.js', array(), null, false );
```

Make a notice, it's placed in `<head>` so it will be run before our script.

**3.** Add the basic cube to the script:

```
<script type="module">

// Find the latest version by visiting https://cdn.skypack.dev/three.

import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.137.5';

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
            const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

            const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
            const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
            const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            scene.add( cube );

            camera.position.z = 5;

            function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
                cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            };

            animate();


</script>
```

for NPM type="module" and `import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.137.5';` is not needed. Because we have imported it already using UMD.

*I might update it in the future for Webpack bundler integration.*